# How to add an attribute with array of integers data type in sails.js model?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, model, sails.js, waterline

I'm using sails with postgresql and I have a user with an array of group ids. I want to save the group id in the user table. my user model is like:

```
    module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    first_name: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    last_name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    company: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 6,
      required: true,
      columnName: "password"
    },

    user_groups: {
      model: 'groups',
    }
  }
```

but when I send a request like [2] I get the error of :

> Could not use specified `user_groups`.  Expecting an id representing
>   the associated record, or `null` to indicate there will be no
>   associated record.  But the specified value is not a valid
>   `user_groups`.  Instead of a number (the expected pk type), got: [ 2 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a many-to-one association in Waterline, the syntax is a little different. In that object for that field, you need `collection` and `via` (the name of the corresponding field in the associated collection). So in the `User` (for convention, I am making the model name singular and PascalCase) it would be something like:

```
user_groups: {
    collection: 'Group',
    via: 'users'
}
```

While in the `Group` model, you have:

```
users: {
    collection: 'User',
    via: 'user_groups'
}
```

Comment: it works, but the app generates a table with name groups_users__users_user_groups that keep user id and the user groups id. do you know how should I remove the rows from groups_users__users_user_groups table when I want to delete a user??